# Publishing to ActiveMQ topic doesn't work

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I wrote a Publisher class in java in order to send messages over a topic.

```
package com.jms.jms_ps;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.jms.*;

/**
 *
 * @author achref
 */
public class Publisher {
    
    Context ctx;
    TopicConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    Topic topic;
    TopicConnection connection;
    TopicSession session;
    
    TopicPublisher publisher;
    
    
    Publisher() throws NamingException{
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
            props.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "tcp://localhost:61616");
            
        ctx = new InitialContext(props);
        
        connectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
        topic = (Topic) ctx.lookup("dynamicTopics/myTopic");
        
    }
    
    void sendTextMessage(String msg) throws JMSException{
        connection = connectionFactory.createTopicConnection();
        session = connection.createTopicSession(true, 0);
        publisher = session.createPublisher(topic);
        
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
        message.setText(msg);
        
        connection.start();
        publisher.publish(message);
        connection.close();
        
    }
    
}
```

The problem is every time I try to send a message it doesn't add to my topic (`Messages Enqueued` is equal to zero) and therefore a subscriber receives nothing.
[ActiveMQ console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkGmR.png)

Comment: Maybe you don't have a client connected while publishing your message?

Comment: Instead of using `0` when creating your session I recommend you use [`javax.jms.Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#SESSION_TRANSACTED) so that the mode you're using is more clear and you can avoid silly mistakes like this.

Comment: Also, creating a connection, session, & publisher for _every_ message you send is a well-known anti-pattern. At the very least you should create the connection once and re-use it.

Comment: Finally, there's no need to invoke [`start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#start--) on your `javax.jms.Connection` instance if you're just sending messages. That method controls the flow of messages for _consumers_ as noted in the JavaDoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending a message in a transacted mode, but not committing the transaction. Ack mode = 0 is Session.TRANSACTED. You need to invoke session.commit() to permit the broker to deliver messages to the topic, or choose a different Acknowledgement mode for your use case.